# Identityserver4 with SPA without redirecting to Login Page

Tags: identityserver4

How can I use SPA (in my case, it is vuejs) with identityserver. In their demo application of javascript client, they have used redirection to login page to get identity. But I want to login from my own page. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the npm package [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js)?

It supports multiple ways to login using the high-level UserManager class. These are:

- Redirection (what you find in the demo)
- Using a pop-up
- Using an iframe

**EDIT**: The iframe option can only be used for a silent non-interactive re-authentication. A typical scenario would be if you access token expired (e.g. after one hour) and you still have a valid session on your identity provider, oidc-client can perform a silent login in the background.

If you want a more embedded experience and client and identity provider are controlled by the same organisation you could resort to using the resource owner password flow (`password`) and send username and password directly from you spa-ui. However keep in mind that access-tokens should not be long lived in pure SPAs (<1h) as there is a high risk they can get compromised. This would mean your users will have to constantly reenter their passwords.

Let me know in the comments (or edit your original question) if you need more advice on how to implement one of these particular solution

Comment: You gave me my answer. But I m gonna contact you in case of any problem of implementation. 

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have a different solution to this problem, which might be more correct, but I'm not sure at all!

First of all, I discovered that there is a parameter to the authorize endpoint called `acr_values` which when has the value of e.g. `idp:Microsoft` directs the authorization server to automatically redirect to an external provider (just what we want!) - but apparently just sending this parameter to *IdentityServer4* does nothing special, it is mostly ignored. What happens is that it is stored and can be retrieved by your code.

So next, I modify `/Identity/Account/Login` and retrieve this parameter by first injecting `IIdentityServerInteractionService` and then calling `GetAuthorizationContextAsync` on it thus:

```cs
var authReq = await _identityServerInteractionService.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
```

The returned object has a property called `IdP` which gets its value from the `idp:...` value of the `acr_values` parameter mentioned above. I then test that the value is a supported external login just to avoid errors, thus:

```cs
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authReq?.IdP)) {
    if (ExternalLogins.All(x => x.Name != authReq.IdP)) {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Unknown login provider {authReq.IdP}");
    }
    else {
        // ... See below for this part
    }
}
```

Then, I return a challenge response that redirects the user to some external provider. This part is copied from `/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin` and slightly adapted, thus:

```cs
var provider = authReq.IdP;
var redirectUrl = Url.Page("./ExternalLogin", pageHandler: "Callback", values: new { returnUrl });
var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
```

And finally, I change the SPA code to send this `acr_values` parameter, this is based on the dotnet `angular` template, which uses `oidc-client`. The code is found in `src\api-authorization\authorize.service.ts` in the function `ensureUserManagerInitialized`, the code that the dotnet template generates is this:

```js
const settings: any = await response.json();
settings.automaticSilentRenew = true;
settings.includeIdTokenInSilentRenew = true;
```

And I changed it to this:

```js
const settings: UserManagerSettings = {
  ...await response.json(),
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  includeIdTokenInSilentRenew: true,
  acr_values: 'idp:Microsoft',
};
```

Comment: Just to understand, this is turning your SPA into an external login page?

Comment: @MB tried this on my local. Adding this property skips the IdentityServer Login page (The login form + External login button) and straight away takes you to the external login page